# Did Esau, Samson, and Saul have ADHD? Have any Rabbis in the past suggested something akin to this?

Tags: sources-mekorot, psych-mentalhealth

The following paper

> Martinez-Badía, J., & Martinez-Raga, J. (2015). Who says this is a modern disorder? The early history of attention deficit hyperactivity disorder. World journal of psychiatry, 5(4), 379–386. https://doi.org/10.5498/wjp.v5.i4.379

states this:

> **It is possible to find clues and highly suggestive descriptions of individuals presenting symptoms resembling what is currently defined as ADHD** in the literature, in paintings or **in the Bible**

and it also states this:

> **Likewise, Merzon et al[27] recently suggested that Esau, the first son of Isaac and Rebecca (Genesis, 25:36), Samson, one of the Judges of Israel (Judges, 13:16) and Saul, the first King of Israel (Samuel 1, 9:31) had clear symptoms of executive dysfunction and possibly ADHD** in a study that correlated behavioral patterns of biblical characters with symptoms of ADHD and executive dysfunction. Another likely example of what could be identified as a possible ADHD can be found in the Deuteronomy, within the Old Testament, were it advised parents troubled by a stubborn and unruly son to denounce him to the city fathers, so that he might be stoned (Deuteronomy 21: 18-21)[28].

My question is whether any Rabbis in the past also held a similar view of the aforementioned individuals. Of course, the Rabbis wouldn't have used the same terminology, but I'm looking for general concepts behind them.

Comment: Three months early?

Comment: @shmosel I'm sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: probably @shmosel thinks this is Purim-Torah

Comment: @setszu ADHD has only been recognised for a few decades, so you'd only be talking about very recent Rabbonim

Comment: There's the Midrash that *in utero*, Esau would wiggle when his mother passed a house of pagan worship, while Jacob would wiggle when passing a house of monotheistic study. Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch suggests that it wasn't that Esau *in utero* was evil or pagan, per se, but that the style of worship (more wild) was his thing. Esau then wound up straitjacketed, trying to be raised just like a Jacob, who liked quiet study.  Not sure I'd call that clinical ADHD per se, but something along the lines of people having different learning styles.

Comment: As for "the rebellious son" who gets executed (at least in theory), the Talmud's definition is that he has to steal from his parents, use the money to buy lots of meat and wine, and consume them. The thinking is that he'll grow up to become a thief to feed his habits, and likely kill someone sooner or later. You could call that a problem of impulse control, perhaps; I don't think ADHD would be the right description.

Comment: This just goes to show what sort of silliness gets published in academic papers nowadays.

Comment: @Shalom Thank you so much, that's very helpful.

Comment: @N.T. I wouldn't say that. I think it's important and fine.

Comment: @MosesSupposes I'm less looking for a Rabbi saying "Esau had ADHD" and more like "Esau was a highly impulsive individual, etc.". More of a categorical description from Rabbis than an ADHD label

Comment: Ok but did Iyov have PTSD? 